# How to add toggle button to a web page designed in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I have tried doing:
ToggleButton t = new ToggleButton();
layout.addComponents(t);

How can i add a toggle button to a web page using vaadin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should work.

You have to add the addon to your maven build and don't forgert to recompile the widgetset

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/togglebutton

Comment: hi, i am not using vaadin designer,but coding in eclipse(vaadin project). Is there any other way to add a toggle button.http://stackoverflow.com/users/599765/andr%c3%a9-schild

Comment: @msv The link above works without the designer as well. Just install the component and compile the widgetset

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Try this code...
    // 1). Created custom Toggle Button using Vaadin Flow.
    // 2). No dependencies.
    // 3). You can change its color as per your requirement.
        
        package com.vaadin.ui.customcomponents;
        import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
        import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
        
        public class CustomToggleButton extends VerticalLayout {
        
            public static final String UNCHECKED_BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#CCCCCC";
            public static final String CHECKED_BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#3375C2";
            public static final String CIRCLE_COLOR = "#FFFFFF";
            private boolean value = false;
        
            public CustomToggleButton(int width, int height) {
                this.setWidth(width + "px");
                this.setMinWidth(width + "px");
                this.setHeight(height + "px");
                this.setMinHeight(height + "px");
        
                this.setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
                this.getStyle().set("background-color", UNCHECKED_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
                this.getStyle().set("padding", "4px 8px 4px 8px");
                this.getStyle().set("border-radius", "30px");
                this.setAlignItems(Alignment.START);
        
                HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
                horizontalLayout.getStyle().set("background-color", CIRCLE_COLOR);
                horizontalLayout.getStyle().set("border-radius", "100px");
                horizontalLayout.setWidth(((width - 10) /2) + "px");
                horizontalLayout.setHeight(((width - 10) /2) + "px");
        
                this.add(horizontalLayout);
                this.addClickListener(event -> {
                   changeValue();
                });
            }
        
            public void setValue(boolean value) {
                this.value = value;
                if (this.value) {
                    this.getStyle().set("background-color", CHECKED_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
                    this.setAlignItems(Alignment.END);
                }
                else {
                    this.getStyle().set("background-color", UNCHECKED_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
                    this.setAlignItems(Alignment.START);
                }
            }
        
            public boolean isValue() {
                return value;
            }
        
            public void changeValue() {
                value = !value;
                if (this.value) {
                    this.getStyle().set("background-color", CHECKED_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
                    this.setAlignItems(Alignment.END);
                }
                else {
                    this.getStyle().set("background-color", UNCHECKED_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
                    this.setAlignItems(Alignment.START);
                }
            }
        }
```